# URL Rewriting with .htaccess redirects

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

i am trying to Generate

```
http://example.com/file/1.php?name=the-file-name-any&id=32vr&code=1548393
```

to

```
http://example.com/file/the-file-name-any.32vr/1548393
```

but i am not success

my .htaccess redirect code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /file/1.php?the-file-name-any=$1&id=$2&code=$3 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^file/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /file/1.php?name=$1&id=$2&code=$3 [L]
```

Make sure it is at the top of your `.htaccess` and you've cleared your cache before testing.